# "mods" tag as it applies to modded consoles

Tags: discussion

Looking at this question:

[What's these files in PSP?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37412/whats-these-files-in-psp)

This person is using a modded PSP firmware revision.  According to this meta thread:

[What's the official stance on hacked/modded consoles?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258/whats-the-official-stance-on-hacked-modded-consoles)

It should be tagged 'mods' - but the description for the mods tag talks about game mods, and not console mods.

Should the question be tagged mods, and the tag changed to include console mods?  Or should the question just be left as-is?  Or is there option #3 that I'm not thinking of :)

Comment: Option #3 would be to create a new hardware-mods tag.

Comment: I've done that for now, and if that's the accepted answer, then awesome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is my personal opinion that "game mods" and "system mods" are different things and deserve different tags.

I propose the following:

- [system-mods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-mods) for modifications to gaming systems (hardware/firmware/software) to make the system do things for which it was not intended.
- [mods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mods) with ([game-mods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-mods) as a synonym) for modifications to games (ie, adding extra features, game modes, bug fixes and similar)

Nobody seems that interested in debating this further, so all THREE questions in the [mods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mods) category that were actually [system-mods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-mods) have been retagged.

Comment: I'd prefer [tag:hardware-mods] personally.

Comment: See Mark's post, not all system/console mods are hardware-mods.

Answer (score 0):

You're not modding hardware with the PSP: you're modifying its operating system, which is still software.

A hardware mod would be installing [a new hard drive in your PS3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2723/ps3-hard-drive-replacement-will-a-3-5-ata-hard-drive-work) or [replacing the fan in your Xbox 360](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/249/will-replacing-stock-fan-ban-my-console). But we already have a tag for those: [upgrades](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upgrades), which is perhaps not surprisingly being used for "How do I upgrade my character/stats/gear/etc.?" questions as well.

If there *really* needs to be a differentiation between game mods and system mods (why?), something like this should probably be done:

- [game-mods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-mods) for game mods
- [system-mods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-mods) (with the synonyms [cfw](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cfw) and [custom-firmware](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/custom-firmware)) for OS-level mods like the PSP CFW.

If not, [software-mods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-mods) should be fine.

In either case, it would then allow for an unambiguous "I'm messing with my system's internal components in such a way that's unsupported and probably going to void my warranty" tag, [hardware-mods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware-mods).

Comment: I'm still pretty confused.  The 'mods' tag talks about "game modifications" - things like changing the text size in Oblivion and what CounterStrike is to Half-Life.  I (personally) think there's a pretty big difference between that and "modifying your console."  However, I don't know that the difference between modifying your console by flashing a rom, and modifying your console by cracking it open and soldering a chip is as big.  Maybe system-mods is a good middle ground then?