# Why was this question closed for having illegal content?

Tags: discussion, closing, site-policies

[Is my 3DS bricked?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/306852/is-my-3ds-bricked)

This question deals with [homebrew](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homebrew), which on it's own is not illegal (homebrew is the means of running 'custom' applications on a device (usually a console) that are not officially authorized by the designer of the console). On their own they are not forbidden.

While I can understand if the above question were closed for being too user specific or for simply being off-topic due to not being about gaming, it doesn't make sense for it to be locked because of "Illegal Content".

The closing reason doesn't make sense to me as the question doesn't concern anything about Unreleased games and most *certainly* is not illegal according to earlier established policy in [When does a question “support piracy and pirated games”?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7549/102076)
 as [homebrew](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homebrew) isn't neccesarily used to run pirated games, but can also be used to break free from the limits imposed by the system developers, allowing other developers to expand the system, even when the system developers have moved on from the device or to improve security on the device in question. (examples of legal 3DS homebrew for this situation includes Custom themes and Badges, notification editors, save editors and ROM hacks). While it's true that Homebrew can be used for piracy, it goes in this case with much the same type of reasoning as jailbreaking an iOS device, as one can use it for piracy, but the existence of a jailbreak itself is not illegal.

Therefore I'd like to ask here "What is our stance on homebrewing/modded gaming devices"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I consider homebrewing a subset of modding your console. And wouldn't you know it, we already have discussed our stance on that:

[What's the official stance on hacked/modded consoles?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258/whats-the-official-stance-on-hacked-modded-consoles)

both of the highest voted answers are in favor of allowing questions about modding, and the answers that are opposed have only a fraction of the upvotes that the answers in favor have.

In my opinion, as long as you don't try to run games that you don't own a license to run or cheat in multiplayer games, it's fine.